# Printing contents of controls in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have never printed anything using C#. I was just wondering what the standard way to do this was. On my form I have a few listboxes and a few textboxes. I would like to print their contents and show them in a print preview, with a nice layout in a table. Then from their I would like the user to be able to print.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use System.Drawing.Printing libraries. You'll use the PrintDocument.Print method which you can find on the [MSDN Page with Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print%28lightweight%29.aspx)

Comment: This method was perfect seeing as how I already have the user save the information to a text file. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting a "Content not found" error, when I follow the MSDN link you've provided.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [nice little tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/simpleprintingcs.aspx) on basic printing in C#. It deals with text but could be extended easily to draw anything else.

Printing in C# is very similar to custom painting in C#. The big difference is that the coordinate system is flipped from the screen representation and that you have to account for spanning of pages (if/when necessary.) The way you print is also a bit counter intuitive in that you have to initiate the print process and then handle the page print event.

**Example:**

Here is a simple example of a print event handler that assumes the presence of list box control named listBox1 with some items in it. It draws each item as well as a box around it.

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 10f);
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Pen rectPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2f);
    Brush brush = Brushes.Black;

    // find widest width of items
    for (int i=0; i<listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        if(maxItemWidth < (int)g.MeasureString(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), font).Width)
            maxItemWidth = (int)g.MeasureString(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), font).Width;

    // starting positions:
    int itemHeight = (int)g.MeasureString("TEST", font).Height + 5;
    int maxItemWidth = 0;
    int xpos = 200;
    int ypos = 200;

    // print
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        g.DrawRectangle(rectPen, xpos, ypos, maxItemWidth, itemHeight );
        g.DrawString(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), font, brush, xpos, ypos);

        ypos += itemHeight;
    }

    e.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

Comment: Should `Pen rectPen` be explicitly disposed of, or does the GC handle that?

Comment: The GC does not handle that. But this is also not a great example. The three painting objects in this code sample, Font, Pen and Brush, are something I would actually declare at class scope instead of recreating them every time the PrintPage handler is called. I would suggest that you do the same in your other code. If I recall you had using statements wrapped around some Pens and Brushes. That's overkill and makes code harder to read. Just move those objects to class scope and let them exist for the life of the app.

Comment: I like the [nice little tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9282/Simplified-NET-Printing-in-C) you have provided as link. Thank you, quite easy to use!

Answer (score 2):

One method is [summarized nicely here at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/printawinformsusercontrol.aspx) having a Print implementation.
As for [Print Preview, somebody has tackled an implementation here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/CoolPrintPreviewDialog.aspx).