# How to print a windows form without a background

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

The client I'm working with wants to be able to print the data they've generated in my application. I know that you can take what amounts to a screenshot of the application and print that, but it looks terrible to have the light gray form background (and since my client will be printing 30+ of these a day, that would waste a lot of ink).

I've tried setting the background of all controls to white just before the form prints, but the color change doesn't get applied until the next draw.

Does anyone know how I can print the contents of a windows form without a light gray background behind everything?

Comment: Why are you bother with printing the form in the first place, instead of properly just printing that data?

Comment: @KenWhite because I don't know how to just print the data. I haven't been able to find any good references or tutorials.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from hacking around the issue, the end result is going to be an image captured at screen resolution then printed at some other resolution - either stretched and ugly or small and harder to read.  Printing isn't that hard, and the results are much prettier.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1683630/920669) shows the basics and there are plenty of tutorials and samples online about how to do things like [print preview](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38758/An-Enhanced-PrintPreviewDialog).

Answer (score 0):

After you have set the color to White, you can call:

```
myForm.Repaint();
Application.DoEvents();
```

That should change the color immidiately.

Comment: I don't know why the downvote. I have upvoted it to remedy the injustice.